# Make div disappear and appear by clicking another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created two divs and I want the one div to disappear and appear by clicking the other one. I tried using Jquery and javascript, but it doesn't seem to be working. Basically, I want the blue one to disappear and appear by clicking the red one.

```js
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', () => {
document.getElementById('blue').classList.toggle('blue');
});
```

```css
#red{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: red;
}
#blue{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue" class="blue"></div>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your JS code in the question

Comment: _" I tried using Jquery and javascript"_ Please include that code so that we can see what you've tried and don't waste your time and ours possibly duplicating your efforts

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't forget, I purposefully left it out, because I found a variety of answers on the Internet.

Comment: The basic idea is `red.click()` causes `blue.toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for example...

```js
$(function(){
  $("#red").on('click', function(){
      console.log('click on red div');
      $("#blue").toggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
  });
});
```

```css
#red{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: red;
}
#blue{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just curious, why don't simply change the selector from `id` to `class` (`#blue` to `.blue` ) in the CSS:

```js
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('blue').classList.toggle('blue');
});
```

```css
#red{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.blue{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue" class="blue"></div>
```